# Make writeable dir for www-data and user

Tags: unix, nginx, debian

I'm new to Linux (using Debian). How to make writeable dir for user and for web-server?

I connect to server via ssh, upload my files. And run next commands:

```
 sudo chown -R www-data:www-data writeable/
 sudo chmod -R g+rw writeable/
```

Then nginx and php (running by www-data user) writes files to `writeable`. Auter that i do not able to edit or delete those files.

Please help me. I know what that question was asked a million times, but i could not to find solution. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure to understand, but I guess you want your dir to be writable for user "www-data" and for another user, let's call it "medvedev".

You can put both users in a group, and grant write permissions for owner (www-data) and group.

```
useradd -G medvedev www-data
```

Comment: What is i upload files by myself, so them belongs to `medvedev` user. How to grant write premissison for owner (medvedev) and to www-data?

Comment: then you could add www-data to the group "medvedev". useradd -G www-data medvedev. However, this would probably be a bad idea, giving too much access to www-data. I would recommend to change the owner (your chown) , and then add medvedev to the www-data group

Comment: Thanks you! Will try to do this.